# How to hide your ip information when visiting a website?

Tags: ip

I am a data collection worker, and I usually have a large number of website resource collection tasks, how to hide my IP information when collecting. I do not want to be traced to my personal information by others. So how to do it?

Comment: I googled your title: "How to hide your ip information when visiting a website?" and got quite a lot of high quality results. Please make sure that you have done at least a little searching before posting here.

Answer (score 3):

There are a couple of options that you can use to hide your personal IP address, the three that are the most obvious / easiest to use are:

**VPN**

There are a number of vendors out there that offer VPNs with output through many different servers usually across many different countries. For example, [SurfShark](https://surfshark.com/). By using a VPN the IP address that the site will see is that of the VPN server, not your personal IP.

It is worth noting, it depends who is hosting the site you are collecting data from and their desire to 'unmask' you. If you are talking about companies then this is the easiest (in my opinion) and a good enough route. However bear in mind if the VPN provider has logs and it is theoretically possible given enough resources, time, etc. that someone could find out who you are.

**Proxy**

Like VPNs, there are many proxies available on the internet. Essentially this is providing the same type of service as a VPN but only sending the web traffic through the remote server, not all your network traffic. An example of a proxy is [KProxy](https://kproxy.com/).

The same caveat applies to proxies that apply to VPNs.

**Tor**

Probably the most effective way of hiding your identity is to use [Tor](https://www.torproject.org/). Given that the project was originally devised by the US Navy to hide traffic from US Government people in foreign countries, this is going to be much harder for anyone to work out who you are. The traffic gets sent via the Tor network and the website owner will simply know that the traffic originates from Tor and not who is at the end of the request.

While this is the most effective way of hiding who you are, there are likely to be a couple of downsides, mainly I believe it will be slower as your traffic is bounced around the Tor network before reaching the destination.

**Summary**

Assuming that you are using a script on a machine to collect data from sites in a way that is unlikely to raise suspicion etc. then I would simply install and run a VPN on that computer before using the script.

Comment: It might be worthwhile to note that some services will block traffic from commercial VPNs and proxies, and Tor nodes.